# MongoDB add description or comment to collection

Tags: mongodb

I have lot of collections in my mongodb database.

I'm many times confused, for which purpose I have created that collection.

Is there any option to add a **comment or description** to a collection in database?

So, when i see the `stats()`, I can see my comment or description as below

```
db.collection.stats()
{
    "comment" : "MY COMMENT HERE",
    "ns" : "data.collection",
    "count" : 85753733,
    "size" : 157014792624,
    "avgObjSize" : 1830.996589081434,
    "storageSize" : 213224434176,
    "numExtents" : 122,
    "nindexes" : 4,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000058983376,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 10543843184,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 2783470144,
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct way to add a comment to a collection. As MongoDb creates collections on demand, there often wouldn't a moment to specify the description. As you can also [see](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/), even when creating programmatically, there is no way to specify it.

You will need to record the information elsewhere. You could create a collection that stored the meta data if you wanted it to be part of the database. If you're using an ORM of some flavor, you might also consider the documentation in your source to be sufficient for a production system.

Answer (score 0):

Write it into your project's technical documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to store additional informations.

```js
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "contacts",
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      title: "Contacts",
      description: "Contact list."
    }
  }
})
```

```js
db.getCollectionInfos({ name: "contacts" })
```